# Unable to create notification integration in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Unable to create notification integration in Snowflake.

- Snowflake region: Canada Central
- Cloud provider: Microsoft Azure

What I've run:

```
CREATE NOTIFICATION INTEGRATION olesia_iot_bucket_changes
TYPE = QUEUE
NOTIFICATION_PROVIDER = GCP_PUBSUB
ENABLED = TRUE
GCP_PUBSUB_SUBSCRIPTION_NAME = 'projects/my_project_name/subscriptions/my_subscription_name';
```

What I've got:

```
SQL compilation error: invalid value 'QUEUE - GCP_PUBSUB' for property 'Integration Type'
```

Comment: It almost sounds like the order of parameters is not ok. Can you try using using the order **enabled, type, notification provider** ?

Comment: It looks like GCP pubsup queue can only be used on AWS or GCP for auto ingestion via Snowpipe. See more information here: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/data-load-snowpipe-auto-gcs.html#cloud-platform-support